# How to make a JSON parse object prototype less in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I had a JavaScript object that is prototype-less.

```
var foo = Object.create(null);
```

Then I read a JSON file (in Node.js) and used `JSON.parse()` to assign it to `foo`. Like this:

```
fs.readFile('talks.json', 'utf8', function(err, text) {
  if (err) {
    throw error;
  }
  foo = JSON.parse(text);
});
```

But when I checked the prototype of `foo` it is not `null` anymore as it was originally intended to be.

Is there a way to make `foo` prototype-less again?

Comment: you've changed the value of `var foo` to a new Object, the one created by `JSON.parse(text)`. But you only want to copy the properties over. `Object.assign(foo, JSON.parse(text))`

Comment: @Thomas You should write that as an answer

Comment: @Thomas, I will accept the answer if you write it. Its correct, I believe.

Comment: @Thomas Nice! There is an answer below from Evgeniy which uses your solution recursively to make this work for any given JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON.parse() method accepts a callback that could be used to transform object into prototypeless object.

```
JSON.parse(string, function(k, v) {
   if (v && typeof v === 'object' && !Array.isArray(v)) {
     return Object.assign(Object.create(null), v);
   }
   return v;
});
```

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/proposal-add-an-option-to-omit-prototype-of-objects-created-by-json-parse

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the solution I found was using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
var prototypeLessTalks = Object.create(null);
var talksParsed = JSON.parse(readFileContent('./talks.json', 'utf8'));

Object.assign(prototypeLessTalks, talksParsed); // here

function readFileContent(fileName, encoding) {
  return fs.readFileSync(fileName, encoding, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    return data.toString();
  });
}
```

**Object.assign()** does not override properties already existing of the destination object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure about that but I think the issue here is that the javascript vm has to assign a prototype. If you check the prototype with `.prototype`, the value is `undefined`. If you check with `.__proto__` it's a blank object.

This makes sense since the prototype shouldn't be nothing even if it's not defined. Programmers shouldn't use `.__proto__`. If you have to check the prototype, use `.prototype`.

```js
var foo = Object.create(null);
console.log(foo); //{}
console.log(foo.__proto__); //undefined
console.log(foo.prototype); //undefined

var foo = JSON.parse("{\"a\":\"bla\"}");
console.log(foo); //like in the JSON string
console.log(foo.__proto__); //{}
console.log(foo.prototype); //undefined
```

Comment: That's  not the issue. The issue here is misunderstanding of variable assignment. Variable assignment in js works like in most other language. You can't automagically convert object types using just variable assignment. For example if you do `var foo = 1` then do `foo = "hello"` you should not expect `foo instanceof Number` to still be true.